# Prove that $ d(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix} 2-x-y &, \, \text{if}\ x\neq y \\ 0 &,\, \text{if}\ x=y \end{matrix}\right. $ is a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

prove if this is a metric space or not:

for $x,y \in [0,1]$, is defined $d:[0,1]\times [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$
d(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
2-x-y &,\, \text{if}\  x\neq y \\ 
0 &,\, \text{if}\  x=y 
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

I have already proved for a) $d(x,y)\geq 0$ and b) $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$

but I am not sure how to do:

c) $d(x,x)=0$

d) $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$

I am thinking that it is not a metric space but don´t know how to do c) and d) to prove it, if you can give me some insight I would apreciate it a lot

Comment: There's a bit you're missing in (c): $d(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$. See if you can find choices for $x$ and $y$ which make this property fail.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I forgot to add that part of the definition.

Comment: Yes, this is why defining the metric piecewise is important--so we can separately consider the $x=y$ case. Using that $x$ and $y$ are restricted to the interval $[0,1]$ ends up playing a role too, as seen in Adronicus's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one comes straight from the definition.

We can split the third one into two cases:

1. If $z=x$ or $z=y$, then the equality holds (from the definition), for example if $z = x$, then the inequality can be rewritten to $d(x, y) \leq d(x, x) + d(x, y) = 0 + d(x, y) = d(x, y)$.
2. Suppose $x \neq y \neq z \neq x$.

$$d(x, z) +d(z, y) = 4 - x - 2z - y = 2 - x - y + (2 - 2z) = d(x, y) + 2(1 - z) \geq d(x, y) $$

Because $1 \geq z$.

P.S.: To address Glare's comment, if $x \neq y$, then suppose $x < y$ (*). Now from the definition we know, that $x < 1$ (strong inequality because of (*)). From that $d(x, y) = 2 - x - y > 0$.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, now I understand it much better